# How to loop object inside an object using For loop

Tags: javascript, angular, loops, typescript

I am currently working on an angular 5 application and stuck at doing validations. I have a form with name, email, gender and address. I have grouped city, state, country into address using `FormGroupname`. I have written a `for` loop in the component to loop through the `valueChanges` in the form and throw errors using the `Validators`. Below is my code :

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.createLoginForm();
  }

   validationMessages = {
    name: {
        required: 'Name is required.',
    },
    email: {
        required: 'Email is required.',
    },
    gender: {
        required:'Gender is required.'
    },
    city: {
        required: 'City is required.',
    },
    state: {
        required: 'State is required.',
    },
    country: {
        required: 'Country is required.',
    },
  registerFormErrors = {
     name: '',
     email: '',
     gender: '',
     address:{
         city:'',
         state:'',
         country:'',
     }
}

createLoginForm(): void {
this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
name: ['', [Validators.required]],
email: ['', [Validators.required]],
gender: ['',[Validators.required]],
sur_name: ['', [Validators.required]],
address: this.fb.group({
  city: ['',[Validators.required]],
  state: [''],
  country: ['',[Validators.required]],
})      

this.registerForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => 
                        this.validateRegisterForm(data));

  validateRegisterForm(data: any): void {
     if (!this.registerForm) return;
       for (let field in this.registerFormErrors) {
         this.registerFormErrors[field] = '';
         let input = this.registerForm.get(field);
            if (input.invalid && input.dirty || input.invalid) {
              for (let errors in input.errors) {
                 this.registerFormErrors[field] = this.validationMessages[field][errors];
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In the above code I am able to loop through the `registerFormErrors` but the problem is with address. As the address is an object, I am not able to loop the address group fields. How can I modify my for loop so that I can loop through all the values along with address object.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a loop that checks if the value is an Object. If it is an Object you have to loop over the keys.

```js
let example = {
     name: 'Foo',
     email: 'Bar',
     gender: 'Male',
     address:{
         city:'A',
         state:'B',
         country:'C',
     }
}

Object.keys(example).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof example[key] === "object") {
        Object.keys(example[key]).forEach(subkey => {
            doValidation(example[key][subkey])
        })
    } else {
        doValidation(example[key]);
    }
})

function doValidation(key) {
    console.log(key);
}
```